# Reschedule Consumer when Queue is full using Timer

Tags: java, timer, timertask

Producer adds the files to be processed in the Queue of the Reader. Reader takes it one by one and process them. Here both these Producer and Reader are scheduled using `Timer`. 
Currently when the Queue is full, the producer waits till the reader is invoked in its next schedule and reads the value.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

**Remover**

```
public class Remover extends TimerTask {
    private ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);
    private static Remover instance = new Remover();

    public synchronized static Remover getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Remover();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> getQueue() {
        return queue;
    }

    public void remove() {
        if (!queue.isEmpty())
            System.out.println("Removing :" + queue.poll());
        else
            System.out.println("Queue is empty to remove");
    }

    public void start() {
        Timer readTimer = new Timer();
        readTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Remover.getInstance(), 0, 10000);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        remove();
    }
}
```

**Adder**

```
public class Adder extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new Worker().add();
    }
}

class Worker {
    public void add() {
        Random random = new Random();
        ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> queue = Remover.getInstance().getQueue();
        for (int i = 0; i < random.nextInt(20); i++) {
            int value = random.nextInt(10);
            while (queue.remainingCapacity() == 0) {
                System.out.println("Queue is full! Wait for sometime!");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Adding: " + value + " is :" + queue.add(value));
        }
    }
}
```

**Tester**

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Remover.getInstance().start();

        Timer writeTimer = new Timer();
        writeTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Adder(), 0, 3000);

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Done
Queue is empty to remove
Adding: 8 is :true
Adding: 0 is :true
Adding: 4 is :true
Adding: 7 is :true
Adding: 0 is :true
Adding: 6 is :true
Adding: 3 is :true
Adding: 4 is :true
Adding: 2 is :true
Adding: 5 is :true
Queue is full! Wait for sometime!
Queue is full! Wait for sometime!
Queue is full! Wait for sometime!
Queue is full! Wait for sometime!
Removing :8
Adding: 6 is :true
Queue is full! Wait for sometime!
Queue is full! Wait for sometime!
Queue is full! Wait for sometime!
Queue is full! Wait for sometime!
Queue is full! Wait for sometime!
Queue is full! Wait for sometime!
```

**The Problem** with this approach is *Producer is waiting* till the Remover is invoked in its next schedule.

*So I thought of rescheduling the Remover from the current moment. So that the waiting time of Producer and sleeping time of Remover would be utilized properly.*

To facilitate this idea, I made the below changes:

**Remover** modified code:

```
private Timer readTimer = null;

public void start() {
    readTimer = new Timer();
    readTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Remover.getInstance(), 0, 10000);
}

public void restart() {
    readTimer.cancel(); 
    readTimer = new Timer();
    readTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Remover.getInstance(), 0, 10000);
}
```

**Adder** modified code:

```
public void add() {
    Random random = new Random();
    ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> queue = Remover.getInstance().getQueue();
    for (int i = 0; i < random.nextInt(20); i++) {
        int value = random.nextInt(10);
        while (queue.remainingCapacity() == 0) {
            Remover.getInstance().restart();
            System.out.println("Queue is full! Restarting the remover!");
        }
        System.out.println("Adding: " + value + " is :" + queue.add(value));
    }
}
```

This produces the below output:

```
Done
Queue is empty to remove
Adding: 7 is :true
Adding: 3 is :true
Adding: 7 is :true
Adding: 2 is :true
Adding: 2 is :true
Adding: 7 is :true
Adding: 6 is :true
Adding: 0 is :true
Adding: 7 is :true
Adding: 6 is :true
Exception in thread "Timer-1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task already scheduled or cancelled
    at java.util.Timer.sched(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Unknown Source)
    at task.Remover.restart(Remover.java:37)
    at task.Worker.add(Adder.java:21)
    at task.Adder.run(Adder.java:10)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
Removing :7
Removing :3
```

While Rescheduling, the `add()` of `Adder` throws an Exception and quits.
How to reschedule the `TimerTask` of `Remover`? What is the reason for this exception?

PS:
I welcome if you are suggesting a better `producer-consumer` model or by using `ExecutorService`. But I'm more interested in understanding the issue in this code!

Comment: Having both producer and consumer run on a timed schedule seems a brittle way to do things; get the timing wrong and the queue will fill up. Why do you want to do that? Why not schedule the producer only, and have the consumer block on the queue, so it waits for work to do?

Comment: @Raedwald The whole idea is - CSV files are placed in a folder continuously. They have to be parsed and processed. Producer is parsing and Remover is processing. Remover code was already running as a scheduled task. I'm trying to complete the workflow by adding the producer.